# how to force stop all checked application from list view in android programmatically

Tags: android, kill-process

In below given code I want to kill (forcestop) all the checked applications but after restarting my application it's showing the name of these killed applications again.

I really don't know if they're really killed or not. Why this is so?

```
kill.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
      @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {

                   //Killing selected Apps 

                    String savedapp;
            int code = 0;
            int count = lv.getAdapter().getCount();

            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                if (lv.isItemChecked(j))
                {
                    Intent ints = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
                    ints.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

                    savedapp = lv.getItemAtPosition(j).toString();
                    nm.removeAll(nm);
                    // this.l = getListView();
                    // l.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

                    List<ResolveInfo> intentlist = pm.queryIntentActivities(ints, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

                    ActivityManager am1 = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

                    List<RunningTaskInfo> processes = am1.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

                    if (processes != null) 
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < processes.size(); i++) {
                            String packageName = processes.get(i).topActivity
                                    .getPackageName();
                            RunningTaskInfo temp = processes.get(i);
                            try
                            {
                                pName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(pm
                                        .getApplicationInfo(packageName,
                                                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
                            } 
                            catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
                            {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        //  int f = 0;
                            if (savedapp.equals(pName)) {
                                // finish(pm.);
                                code = intentlist.get(i).activityInfo
                                        .hashCode();
                                finishActivity(code);

                                am1.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
                                am1.restartPackage(packageName);
                                android.os.Process.killProcess(temp.id);

                                finishActivity(temp.id);

                                // Toast.makeText(this, packageName,
                                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //f = 1;
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                nm.add(pName.trim());
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
}
};//kill button close
```

Comment: my task manager tells me that some apps can't be killed, maybe that is your issue?

Comment: I am talking about third party applications..not about system applications

Comment: Quote from the Task Killer app I use: "Those apps are Services and front apps. They cannot be killed directly in Android 2.2 or later." So even third party apps might be "unkillable"

Comment: Ok..then it is not posssible,why then android have those API

Comment: Because some apps are still killable. Check this app: [Advanced Task Killer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller&hl=de) you will see that quite some apps can be killed (in my case some google apps like chrome, gmail etc)