# killing other applications

Tags: android

i want to kill the sms application when it is open. for this purpose i write a service . that checks if sms application is opened. and if it is then it kills this. i am using `ActivityManager` class. here is my code
but when i launch sms application it nevers ends. why? is it possible ? if yes then please help.

```
package com.example.activitymanager;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

public class Servicee extends IntentService {
    ActivityManager am;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> list = am
                    .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task : list) {
                if (task.baseActivity.getPackageName()
                        .equals("com.android.mms")) {
                    am.restartPackage(task.baseActivity.getPackageName());
                }
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };

    public Servicee() {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);

    }

}
```

Comment: I wrote it once that [some applications can't be killed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744928/how-to-force-stop-all-checked-application-from-list-view-in-android-programmatic#comment22373283_15744928) and beside that, how do you fire the intent to get the app killed?

Comment: using service and get the process id amd kill the process

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Usman Riaz comment but keep in mind, the process id might change from device to device. I wanted to monitor the tpc traffic of a specific app and id didn't work out in the end. You'll kill some other app or crash the system.

Comment: by using `ActivityManager` i can get the running prosecc id by recognizing it by its package name. but you are right, i tried to kill the sms application's prosess but after killing it the prosess was again there with different id

Comment: I want to stop the user from sending sms, is it possible ? there are many apps that does the same.